# Restrict app to access network

Tags: android

I have given my app the '`ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`' and '`CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`' permissions along with '`INTERNET`'. This means my app can connect to internet.
I want to block internet access for the app at some particular time and allow at other times.
Is there any way i can get the control when to allow it to access internet and when to block.

Comment: I really don't understand the purpose of your question. If you don't want a user to access a network at certain times, just check the time and allow it or disallow it.

Comment: I was just wondering whether we can have control over how and when the app can use the internet. In android app if we add a permission we cannot revoke the permission at runtime. So if i add internet access permission i cannot temporarily revoke that permission. Or is there any other to revoke the internet permission of an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify `<uses-permission>` it has two purposes...

1. When a user installs your app it informs them of the type of things your app may do (such as access the Internet) and allows them to agree or not. If they agree, your app will be installed otherwise the install will be terminated.
2. When an app has been installed (which implies the user agreed to the required permissions), your code can use the various system services, classes and methods which require those permissions.

Just because a user approves the installation of an app which requires certain permissions does NOT, however, mean the app has to do anything which requires those permissions.

In conclusion - the declaration of permissions that are needed is primarily a 'contract' between you (the app developer) and the user which then tells the system that the user has approved the use of certain system features or services.

There is no way to revoke what you've declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you don't want users to do certain things at certain times of the day, days of the month etc etc., just check the system time in your code and allow it or not.

Answer (score 0):

As @Squonk said in comment...Is your that "permission" to access netowrk is controlled by a button or action? Then you could use a static Boolean variable and keep all the "network" operations under the condition if that variable is true. And change it's value under the action of the button...